# Issue with colors.xml in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, colors, android-resources, android-studio-3.2

Following is the awkward and incomplete `colors.xml` I get while trying to create an Android project using Android Studio 3.2.1.

[image]

The error I get is `D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\PlayCardz\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:7:19: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.`

Why is it happening?

**Update**

After manually changing colors.xml file to following I start getting the following error:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\GameCardz\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\docrk\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a0fab621f980e2e9b95746cdfd1fc60d\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\GameCardz\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\GameCardz\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Manually updated colors.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--   color for the app bar and other primary UI elements -->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>

    <!--   a darker variant of the primary color, used for
           the status bar (on Android 5.0+) and contextual app bars -->
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>

    <!--   a secondary color for controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Do you have your `New Project` template incorrectly modified? Note that what you say is `create a project`...

Comment: This is during the creation of the project. I haven't done anything to the project yet. It just builds with that error and the colors.xml file.

Comment: Which kind of project are you creating? Consider looking for <AndroidStudio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates to find what happened. `AndroidTVActivity`?

Comment: Update for your update: what is the content of `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26ic_launcher_round.xml`?

Comment: Hello @GenoChen It is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>`

Comment: @GenoChen When I navigate to the file `ic_launcher_background` inside my android project I find it is full of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is copied from `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/res/values/colors.xml`. Check for it to find any error in this file.

For me, the content of this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

Overwrite it if your template is modified.

**Update** for the updated question: I think your project template is totally overwritten with a mess. You may recursively find what the error of your templates are, by finding the source of error output of the file path (for example, the error in the update says file `(D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\GameCardz\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml`, which can be mapped into the template file `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml`.), correct each of them.

Or, since this template locates in `<Android Studio install dir>` (actually it is a bundled plugin), you *may* reinstall your Android Studio, or reinstall (but, how to?) that plugin to fix this issue.

Comment: Hello @Geno Chen I just did that and then I have started getting another issue that I have mentioned in my updated question. Please take a look.

Comment: @skip I updated my answer for your updated question.

Comment: You're spot on about the `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` in the project full of junk. I've copied the content from `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/root/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml` to `D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\GameCardz\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml`. I've updated the `ic_launcher` in the project too. But still I've got errors being shown in the `D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\GameCardz\app\src\main\res\drawable\ic_launcher_background.xml` file.

Comment: I mean the "source", or we say the "template", which locates in `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/`, where the file of your new project generated / copied from, are destroyed with an unknown reason. So what you should do is, to fix the "template", by reinstall Android Studio, or reinstall that Android plugin, or manually fix all the errors in the template, **not** by copying the content from "template" to "generated project".

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to delete .gradle .android and .androidstudio3.x folders in c\useres\username and it went normal again. I think you have updated androidstudio recently.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete `.gradle` `.android` and `.androidstudio3.x` folders in `C:\Users\username` and it went normal again. I think you have updated Android Studio recently.

This worked for me also. My `colors.xml` and `ic_launcher` were corrupted somehow. I built many apps with no issue. Then this weekend I was getting build errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your files from `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule` has been crashed.

1. Download https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+archive/studio-master-dev/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule.tar.gz
2. Go to `<Android Studio install dir>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule`
3. Extract files from `<Name Of Downloaded File>.tar.gz` and Replace All !!!
4. Restart Android Studio