# Resource files (color.xml, string.xml, style.xml)

Tags: java, android

As I am going to open files in the values (color.xml, string.xml, style.xml). they are not showing the text that they have! I don't know why it is happning. if you ever have face this sort of problem. please give me solution.

I have clean the project and rebulit project.

//colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project version="4">
        <component name="AndroidLayouts">
            <shared>
                <config />
            </shared>
        </component>
        <component name="ChangeListManager">
        <list def
```

[image]

Comment: can you please explain more or add screenshots

Comment: whenever I open a file in android studio .. it's getting change automatically .. without any further doing ...! Allthought color.xml file contains about the colors ..., but in this case ... it got change . I couldn't understand the cause of error.

Comment: Maybe its just an installation problem. Please try to uninstall Android Studio and re-install.

Comment: have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781751/issue-with-colors-xml-in-android-studio-3-2-1

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting **.android** and **.AndroidStudio[your version number]** folder from **C:\Users\ [your PC name]**

Also try doing the following (optional)

- DELETE **Project Name.iml** file from you project directory
- DELETE **app.iml** file from your **Project Name**/app directory

**Project Name** is the name of the project that you set when you first created your project in Android Studio.

Relaunch Android Studio.